How to reverse the tokenizer.apply_chat_template()
# Chat template example
prompt = [
    { "role": "user", "content": "Random prompt."},
]

# Applying chat template
prompt = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(chat)


Is there anyway to convert the prompr string back to the original array?
My problem: If I don't use pipeline the response is a string and I need to manually parse it, I'm trying to figure out how pipeline parse it under the hood
